# Python Mechanize, click a <li> link?

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to get my Mechanize script to click a button but it doesn't seem to be a real button, but a link embedded in a list element:

```
<ul class='SomeName' id="SomeID">
<li a="['arbitrary stuff here']" class="blah">
<span class="spanny">TextOnTheButton</span>
</li>
```

How might I tell Mechanize to click this element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `<li>` can only be clickable if Javascript is involved, which mechanize doesn't understand. Thus, you have basically two options:

- Check in a HTTP protocol analyzer like Fiddler or the one integrated in Firebug which query is issued after clicking the link (if a new HTTP request is issued at all)
- Use a Javascript-aware scraper like Selenium or my own little library, [dryscrape](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape) (which is only tested on Linux)

Comment: How might I use Firebug to check this sort of thing? (I have Firebug installed)

Comment: @John Smith: It has a HTTP-analyzer built-in that shows you which requests are issued, along with the server response. Maybe you have to do a bit of reverse-engineering to find out which query is used for what purpose and which one contains the data you need. Then you can use mechanize or urllib2 to issue the same request manually and get the data you want. If what you want is actually *navigate* the website instead of scraping it, dryscrape or Selenium might be your best bets.

Comment: There's https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner too to scrape the web with javascript.